# how to code my discord bot to respond to two or more sets of keywords?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I am a beginner and I just started coding today

I was trying to make a bot that responds to other users in my server by detecting certain keywords in their sentences and then generating a response based on those keywords

This is what I was able to do:

```
import discord 
client = discord.Client()
keywords = ["hey", "hello"]
TOKEN = '*some token here*'
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        if keywords[i] in message.content:
            for j in range(1):
                await message.channel.send("hey there!")
```

As you can see, I coded the bot to respond to messages containing "hey" or "hello" with "hey there!".

Now how can I add another set of keywords with another response?

My goal is to make the bot respond to two or more sets of keywords, with each set of keywords having its own response.

I'm using discord.py btw.

Comment: I would recommend picking up a good book on python before jumping into a complicated library like discord.py

Comment: add another list with keywords, and another code which checks it. And later you can try to reduce it using nested list. OR read documentation for discord because it has special methods to assing function to different keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on your own then you could use dictionary with `{"word": "answer", ...}`

```
import discord 
client = discord.Client()

keywords = {
    "hey": "Hey there!",
    "hello": "Hey there!",
    "bye": "See you later!",
}

TOKEN = '*some token here*'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    
    for word, answer in keywords.items():
        if word.lower() in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send(answer)
```